# Need better simpler solution for conditional link

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have three condition/variable combination e.g. below called *amounts*:

```
$a = 15000; $b = 10000; $c = 5000;
or
$a = 10000; $b = 15000; $c = 0;
or
$a = 12000; $b = 0; $c = 15000;
etc.
```

At least each $a or $b or $c above is not 0 (zero).

If the amount of each not 0 (zero) it have its own associated array e.g. if $b == 0 then $b_array will not set/created, assume all is not 0(zero) then below arrays are created:

```
$a_array = array('id'=>1);
$b_array = array('id'=>2);
$c_array = array('id'=>3);
```

If $a / $b / $c is not 0 (zero) then if $b or $c not zero it needs to be linked to $a or $b (if not zero) as below:

```
if($a != 0 && $b != 0 && $c != 0){
    $b_array['id_link'] = $a_array['id'];
    $c_array['id_link'] = $a_array['id'];
} elseif ($a != 0 && $b != 0 && $c == 0){
    $b_array['id_link'] = $a_array['id'];
} elseif ($a != 0 && $b == 0 && $c != 0){
    $c_array['id_link'] = $a_array['id'];
} elseif ($a == 0 && $b != 0 && $c != 0){
    $c_array['id_link'] = $b_array['id'];
}
```

The result for conditional statement above seems correct as you can check at [the php sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f1dbe013ee5843249a6561a8a2f8d4e38821fa9)

Is there any better idea for the conditional code and is there a missing condition (error handling). Any idea or  solutions is greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: what if the following cases happen ? (1) $a==0 && $b==0 & $c!=0  (2) $a!=0 && $b==0 && $c==0 (3) $a==0 && $b!=0 &&$c==0

Comment: Hi @KenLee Above condition is ignored as at least one of $a or $b or $c must not be 0 (zero) exactly as you stated above. Thanks!!

Comment: I'd check the sum instead.

Comment: @IvanSlaughter, in that case your conditions are already ok. (I dont think the if-then-else are too complicated so if I were you I will accept it since it works and covers everything you want).

Comment: Thanks @KenLee, your thought really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*If I understand your question correctly*, instead of checking for every combination possible, just get the first non zero number and assign it's `id` as `id_link` to all of them like below:

```
<?php

$id_link = -1;

if($a !== 0){
    $id_link = $a_array['id'];
}else if($b !== 0){
    $id_link = $b_array['id'];
}else if($c !== 0){
    $id_link = $c_array['id'];
}


$a_array['id_link'] = ($b_array['id_link'] = ($c_array['id_link'] = $id_link));
```

[**Online Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f94852b09e9796e2891bdbbef0467f27655bc1ad)

(The brackets in the expression are added just for readability since they are redundant in case of PHP)

---

**Update:**

If you wish to leave the array with it's corresponding variable *without the `id_link` key*, then you can just use another 3 if conditions to take care of it.

```
<?php

$id_link = -1;

if($a !== 0){
    $id_link = $a_array['id'];
}else if($b !== 0){
    $id_link = $b_array['id'];
}else if($c !== 0){
    $id_link = $c_array['id'];
}

if($a !== 0){
   $a_array['id_link'] = $id_link;
}

if($b !== 0){
   $b_array['id_link'] = $id_link;
}

if($c !== 0){
    $c_array['id_link'] = $id_link;
}
```

[**Online Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7c1c79b6efb05c0e7b03e44e5e991f2d798c07eb)